# Android- Display everyday information from database in Calender

Tags: database, android-calendar, data-retrieval

I'm developing an android app in which one of the feature is that it should display everyday information retrieved from database, on that particular day. I have a separate form in which the user will enter some information regarding a reminder like TITLE, COURSE, DATE, TIME. Based on the timings i was able to set alarm. But now what i want is that particular TITLE to be displayed in a calender for that particular day.

ex: TITLE: Homework,
    COURSE: CS 5454,
    DATE: 23-04-2014,
    TIME: 08:15 AM

I want this title 'Homework' to be displayed when i open the calender and press on that particular day. This information can be displayed separately in a text view at the bottom.

***Below is an open source image. I wanted something similar to this. Pressing on january 1st show's a message at the bottom, similarly i need all the information retrieved from database for every day***

link: http://goo.gl/2JYpDE

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem.  Add some code to your question and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: I have not yet started coding for this part though, But it's like the general calender in our phones. When we open Calender on our phone, it shows reminder or a note for that particular day. But what i want is like, 
**REMINDERS**
**course**,    **date**,    **professor**:
 _5345_,     _08-13-2014_,   _Wolverine_,
 _5330_,     _07-03-2014_,   _Iron Man_,
 _5331_,     _26-08-2014_,     _Hulk_.
.
.

for the above **REMINDERS** table in database i want to display professor name **Wolverine** on **08-13-2014** in a calender, **Iron Man** on **07-03-2014** in the same calender.I hope i'm clear now.